# How to ignore or handle backspaces in input stream

Tags: java, buffer, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I have a input buffer stream. When I type input text and press backspaces to edit any character the buffer stores backspace. 
Is there any way to ignore backspaces from buffer reader

```
private InputStream inputStream;
private BufferedReader inStream;

 this.inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.inputStream));
```

The output is 
I :AM:TRYINGIED; instead do I AM TIRED;

Any way to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: The backspaces are coming through a socket?

Comment: No, while I am sending text to socket and if i press backspace to correct the text then it get included in it

Comment: Well the code you showed reads from a socket's inputstream. Maybe you should be showing the part where you're reading the user input instead, since that's where the problem is?